# Will SharePoint developers still need asp.net webforms skills for 2013 and beyond?

Tags: development, 2013

Will asp.net webforms skills still be a **requirement** for SharePoint development down the road?  Or will webforms become just one development technology out of many a SharePoint developer can choose from?

Trying to get an idea of a learning plan for possibly transitioning into SP development several years from now.

Answer (score 1):

Those skills are still relevant, web parts are still a big part of SP 2013. They are not replaced by apps but they can be deployed as an app. You can think of an app as a wrapper around a solution file (.wsp), which could be a web part or many other things. Where I work we still deploy everything as solutions and don't bother with apps as we don't have a need for them yet.

[This document shows a nice diagram of how an App relates to a Solution](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30373)

Answer (score 1):

I will be very surprised if all the plumbing gets changed out for non-webforms-based alternatives.  Writing apps is one thing, developing non-trivial enhancements or modifications will likely require at least a solid understanding of the webforms model and what SharePoint is doing with it, even if you do your implementation on a different stack.

You can get by as a limited-scope developer by staying in the apps world.  I wouldn't recommend it at all.  However, "Requirement" is subjective.